# Is there a physical interpretation of the connection between the scattering matrix and bound states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, singularities, s-matrix-theory, quantum-states

The square integrability condition of a scattering wavefunction can be written for imaginary wavenumber $k = -\mathrm{i}\kappa$ as
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}r\left|(-1)^l \mathrm{e}^{-\kappa r} - S_l(-\mathrm{i}\kappa)\mathrm{e}^{\kappa r}\right|^2 < \infty$$
from which we can see that the assumption of a bound state forces a zero in the scattering matrix $S_l$ on the negative imaginary semiaxis which results in a pole on the positive imaginary semiaxis. I have three related questions:

1. We use a scattering wave function to arrive at this conclusion but then suppose also that it represents a bound state. Is there no problem here? How can it represent both kinds of state? The function used is $$\psi \sim ((-1)^l \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}k r} - S_l(k)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k r})\mathrm{exp}(-\mathrm{i} E t / \hbar).$$
2. Is there a more direct physical way of understanding why poles in scattering matrices correspond to bound states? I feel like there is a rich interpretation I am missing.
3. Everyone talks about the pole but never the zero. Is there a reason for this? Just because you'll pick up a pole as a residue in some calculations or something?

Comment: Are you following a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic Scattering Theory by Aleksei G. Sitenko, chapter 7, but especially section 7.5. However you could pop this argument about the bound states in anywhere after roughly chapter 4 and it would be clear.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705893/2451